# From sequence Diagram to Class diagram

Tags: uml, software-design, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I'm trying to understand sequence diagrams and class diagrams. I just don't clearly understand how to find one if you have the other.

for example in this sequence diagram

[image]

to convert it to class diagram I would create three classes : Student, Seminar & Course.

my question is for example the `enrollStudent()` function should I put it as member function of Student class or Seminar class?

Comment: You cannot create a class diagram from a sequence diagram with every detail. Sequence diagrams show how classes interact one each other and don't show classes' attributes, though only methods are shown. Referring to your question, each method is contained by the class the arrow is pointing to. So enrollStudent() method will be contained within Seminar class and would be executed in the method you are representing in this sequence diagram (Studen class).

Comment: You should go and ask the editor. The `getSeminarHistory` towards `Student` seems to be broken as he's an actor and not some kind of database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operation or reception should be on a receiving end, that is in your example enrollStudent should be member of Seminar.

As for creating class diagram from sequence or vice versa - it doesn't work this way. These are different views of the same system and are created more or less in parallel. While dependency between message and class is simple, you see neither logic of sequence on class not the opposite. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to have two diagrams.

Comment: One could re-construct classes from a SD by looking at the messages and create operations from the messages. Of course this is in no way design.

Comment: If you would have a complex sequence diagram with a lot of lifelines, then it could add value to derive a class diagram from it. The class diagram would give an overview of the classes, their relationships and the operations per class. But, true, this is not the usual way of working.

Comment: @ThomasKilian that's true but only if all communications are described through sequence diagrams, which is hardly ever true (or to be more specific - I don't think it is ever true). The goal of sequence diagram is to show complex communication. If there just a simple request/response communication no-one will bother creating sequence diagram.
I believe we agree here, this is only a statement for those readers who might not be aware of this.